# JavaScript to sort DOM elements by some comparator, without jQuery

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-manipulation

Imagine some DOM elements:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li data-index="3">Baz</li>
  <li data-index="1">Foo</li>
  <li data-index="2">Bar</li>
</ul>
```

How can these elements be sorted using JavaScript and without jQuery?

Something similar to:

```
document.getElementById('list').sort(function(li) { return li.dataset.index; });
```

Comment: Try searching for this question online and you'll find nothing out there that covers this other than some jQuery stuff. Seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me. Explain why if you feel otherwise.

Comment: Put references to `li` elements into an array (or convert NodeList into one), sort, and insert elements back into DOM in array order … done.

Comment: @CBroe, that involves a lot of DOM churn, which is bad for performance especially if the list is already mostly sorted. I'd like to do the sort in-place ideally.

Comment: What do you mean by in-place exactly here? Nothing about your shown pseudo-code say “in-place” to me …

Comment: "In-place" sorting would probably be even slower, you'd need to append the same element several times. Btw. I didn't vote down, but maybe the lack of a true attempt to solve this has caused a down-vote.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f4s7s/1/

Comment: @Teemu, I don't see how this would involve appending the same element more than once.  Also, for a simple topic I generally prefer short concise questions. When I search for answers on SO, I find other people's incorrect workings a distraction between the problem and its solution. Each language's community on SO has a different vibe, and the JS one is quick to assume the OP is lazy :)

Comment: @DrewNoakes Maybe I understood "in-place" somehow differently. I don't know about other "language communities", but here under JS tag we've [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341303/export-an-html-table-to-csv) kind of questions far too much : ).

Comment: @Teemu, understood. By in-place I mean that no new array is created, and the elements are manipulated directly (in the parent's `children` collection I suppose). This means that if the items are already sorted, then no actual DOM manipulation occurs. In my case, I'm appending one child to a parent, then re-sorting. So most of the time I just need to insert that one child at the correct index to solve this. However I found no treatment of this topic via Google, so thought it might make an interesting SO question.

Comment: Well if you just need to insert one new element at a time into an already sorted listed of elements – then you could just loop through the existing elements, until you find the first one with a “larger” sort value, and insert the new one before that …

Comment: @CBroe, yeah but it's not always a single element. In other cases the user may change the sort criteria.

Comment: @DrewNoakes The problem with the approach you've described in your comment is, that though HTMLCollections and NodeLists returned by many DOM methods are live, they are not bi-directional. I.e. a change made to a list is not reflected to the DOM.

Comment: @Teemu, interesting. Still can't one just use `insertBefore` on the parent?

Comment: @DrewNoakes, of course you can use `insertBefore`. In the same way as `appendChild`, if an element is in the DOM already, it gets removed from its current position and is inserted at the new one.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the ordering capabilities of flexboxes. This will allow to re-order the elements without moving them around in the DOM. This involves setting the CSS `order` property.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes for more details.

Comment: Good idea, but sadly [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) currently only works for `content` property and strings. In the future, `order: attr(data-index integer)` will be great.

Comment: Nice! Ordering should be a presentation concern. Support seems ok for the browsers I'm targetting (private, controlled deployment) but may not be suitable for everyone just yet: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: @Oriol Don't understand your concern. In the initial code, you can just use `style='order: 1; '` instead of `data-index='1'`. Then, in the sorting code, you can set `elt.style.order` based on the result.

Comment: @torazaburo The problem is that I find inline styles ugly :)

Comment: @Oriol (with a CSS preprocessor) you could easily create a handful of utility classes, which you'd then apply.

Answer (score 3):

Some time ago I wrote this:

```
function sortChildren(wrap, f, isNum) {
    var l = wrap.children.length,
        arr = new Array(l);
    for(var i=0; i<l; ++i)
        arr[i] = [f(wrap.children[i]), wrap.children[i]];
    arr.sort(isNum
        ? function(a,b){ return a[0]-b[0]; }
        : function(a,b){ return a[0]<b[0] ? -1 : a[0]>b[0] ? 1 : 0; }
    );
    var par = wrap.parentNode,
        ref = wrap.nextSibling;
    par.removeChild(wrap);
    for(var i=0; i<l; ++i) wrap.appendChild(arr[i][1]);
    par.insertBefore(wrap, ref);
}
```

Basically:

1. First create an array to store the elements with its corresponding value returned by the comparator function.

   We could also run the function when sorting, but since DOM interactions are slow, this way we make sure the function will only run once per element.
2. Then, we sort it using native `sort`.

   If `isNum` argument is truly, we use a sorting function that compares numerically. This is needed if the comparator function returns strings but you want to compare numerically instead of lexicographically.
3. Now, we remove the wrapper element from the DOM. This way reordering the children will be less expensive (e.g. avoiding repaitings).
4. Finally we reorder the children, and insert wrapper back in its place.

Run it like

```
sortChildren(
    document.getElementById('list'),
    function(li) { return li.dataset.index; },
    true
);
```

or

```
sortChildren(
    document.getElementById('list'),
    function(li) { return +li.dataset.index; }
);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rVRF5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>sort list</title>
</head>
<body>
<strong>Double click the list to sort by data-index</strong>
<ul id= "list">
<li data-index= "3">Baz</li>
<li data-index= "1">Foo</li>
<li data-index= "2">Bar</li>
</ul>
<script>

document.body.ondblclick=function(){
    var A=[], pa= document.getElementById('list');
    var itemz= pa.getElementsByTagName('li');

    A.slice.call(itemz).sort(function(a, b){
        return a.getAttribute('data-index')-b.getAttribute('data-index');
    }).forEach(function(next){
            pa.appendChild(next);
    });
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```