# Jquery sort child elements in DIV tage

Tags: jquery, html

I want to sort elements with in the DIV tag using Jquery. I've used below code, but not working.

Jquery:

```
function onClick() {
    $('#executiongraph > span').toArray().sort(function (a, b) {
        a.id - b.id
    });
}
```

html:

```
<div id="executiongraph">
<span class="actionname" id="40">DummyAction1</span>
<span class="actionname" id="20">DummyAction3</span>
<span class="actionname" id="10">DummyAction2</span>
<span class="actionname" id="30">DummyAction1</span>
</div>
```

Expected o/p:

```
 <div id="executiongraph">
   <span class="actionname" id="10">DummyAction2</span>
   <span class="actionname" id="20">DummyAction3</span>
   <span class="actionname" id="30">DummyAction1</span>
   <span class="actionname" id="40">DummyAction1</span>
 </div>
```

I found Answer:

// get array of elements

```
               var myArray1 = $("#executiongraph span");
               var count = 0;

               // sort based on timestamp attribute
               myArray1.sort(function (a, b) {

                   // convert to integers from strings
                   a = parseInt($(a).attr("id"), 10);
                   b = parseInt($(b).attr("id"), 10);
                   count += 2;
                   // compare
                   if (a > b) {
                       return 1;
                   } else if (a < b) {
                       return -1;
                   } else {
                       return 0;
                   }
               });

               $("#executiongraph").append(myArray1);
```

Comment: first: the sort function does not return anything, second: why do you expect a sorted array of dom nodes have the effect of sorting the dom nodes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10186192/1529630, http://stackoverflow.com/q/24342242/1529630, http://stackoverflow.com/q/11545960/1529630

Answer (score 0):

sort requires you return an integer which controls the sorting. For example in your case you would have something like

```
if(a.id == b.id) return 0; 
if(a.id < b.id) return -1; 
else return 1; // a.id > b.id
```

Also you have some problems with the jQuery code that is handling sorting the elements. First the `call $('#executiongraph > span')` already returns an Array of jquery objects so `toArray()` is redundant. Finally you need to remove the elements from the executiongraph div and then reinsert them in the sorted order.

[This article](http://trentrichardson.com/2013/12/16/sort-dom-elements-jquery/) explains perfectly how to do what you want